# Installing new Pir sensor switches

Tags: smart-switch

I want to install new motion switches to replace old light switches in basement, old switches only have 2 wires hot black, white neutral wire so I will need to run another wire for the load.is their an easy way to do this?[image]

Comment: Be careful, for many years the NEC has specified that If you only have two wires (black and white) serving as a switch loop then the white is suppose to be permanently re-marked (tape or paint) and used as a hot, and the black is a switch leg. That way you have one black and one white connected to the fixture.

Comment: @nosparksplease make that an answer I will up vote. I would also suggest the op get a book on basic wiring and start reading.+

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Can’t figure out how to post a pic But I can tell you all 5 switches Have a ground one white and one black when I unhook the wires and turn power on only black is hot.I will try to include pics tomorrow.

Comment: @PaulWinwood -- hit the "edit" link at the bottom left of your post (in "share edit..."), then use the button that looks like a stylized mountain-and-sun painting to add photos.

Comment: Anyone?ani ideas